# Source multiple files via shell filename completion

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

I'm trying to enable autocompletion of my homebrew commands. Homebrew automatically creates the folder `bash_completion.d` and sym-links all completion files there.

```
$ ls -a `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/
.  ..  brew_bash_completion.sh  git-completion.bash
```

As you can see I have completions for `brew` and `git`. So I try to run the files:

```
[ -d `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d ] && source `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/*
```

This is in my `~/.bash_profile`, and I'm expecting this to source all the files in `bash_completion.d`. When I try it out later in the terminal, only the completion for `brew` works.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `source` help eludes that mystery:

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Read and execute commands from FILENAME and return.  The pathnames
    in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.  If any
    ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
    FILENAME is executed.
```

which means that when you feed it a list of filenames generated through a glob, only the first is sourced, while all filenames after it are considered its arguments. To source all files in your completion directory, you will need to loop over it, i.e.

```
for f in "$(brew --prefix)"/etc/bash_completion.d/*; do source "$f"; done
```

**However**, as you use homebrew’s bash completion, there is a much better way: simply

```
source "$(brew --prefix)"/etc/bash_completion
```

which will take charge of sourcing anything found in the pertinent completion directories, while also adding a plethora of useful completions of its own.